# How to install the apk silently from another application for non rooted device in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to install the apk silently from another application for non rooted device in android.Is it possible to install apk from another application silently or not prompting  widow?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for security reasons.

Comment: sir is it possible if we make app as device admin or device owner or profile owner ? @CommonsWare

Comment: @MohitTrivedi: I am not certain. Of the two, device owner status would be far more likely to support this.